# Variable that apply only to a subset of the data

Tags: machine-learning, data-transform

I'm using a public dataset available at this link.

It's about marketing, and one of the variables (`pdays`, numeric) refers to the number of days that passed by after the client was last contacted from a previous campaign.

Rows which the value is 999 means that the client was not previously contacted. I'm afraid that using this into a ML algorith will lead to wrong results.

I'm thinking of turning them to zero. But I don't know what to do with the zeroes when scaling the dataset before using an algorith (Should I consider the zeroes?).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct about turning this value to 0 but the best practice here is probably to also define a new binary variable. You could name this variable as "Not previously contacted" and for each observation of value 999 assign value 1 to your new variable denoting that the client was not previously contacted, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about adding a new flag variable. But what about the scaling? Should I scale the `pdays` variable with or without the zeroes?

Comment: That is up to you, my following answer is not correct since there are multiple ways to go about it. I would fit the eligible values in a -1 to 1 scale and force all adjusted values (previous 999's) to be 0's in this new scale as a way to center the odd values so that they don't count as statistically significant (neither too high nor too low). Imagine learning a multiple linear regression, namely weights for your variables and a bias. 0's would cancel and not change the value of the output of your model, forcing the model to learn adjustments in other variables (the flag variable) or the bias.